# Puppet remove log if all goes fine

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to remove the log file generated Puppet while executing if it returns an exit code of 0 (all ok and no changes applied) or 2 (all ok and some changes applied)?

The use case is since I have a Satellite that stores the logs reported by the agents. The logs aren't necessary on the agents causing unnecessary disk space usage. But if something goes wrong, I'd like to keep the logs locally on the agent for further diagnosis.

Comment: How are you running the agent? Is there a long running "service" type process, or are you running from `cron` periodically?

Comment: @Felix Frank , puppet is running on demand manually

Comment: You may want to consider aging off old logs rather than having gaps in recent log history. If something goes wrong, you can sometimes look at other adjacent Puppet runs for more context.

Answer (score 1):

Follow your invocation of Puppet with

```
[ $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2 ] && rm -f /path/to/logfile
```

or whatever command is suitable for the task.

Doing this from the Puppet manifest would likely be more difficult than this problem merits.

Comment: I am not sure that this would help, really. The exit status is returned by the Puppet Agent running on the node. His issue is with storing the logs remotely on Satellite. (Puppet Master)

Comment: @AaronCopley the way I read it, the local logs should be purged *because* there are centralized Satellite copies available.

Comment: After reading it again; I agree. :)